# How to detect properly when the player can crush an enemy from above?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This question is much more complex than it seems, here's why.

I have a player and the physic is enabled, in a 2D + 3D world.

The monsters have a sinusoidal movement = they go up and down, from right to left.
The player can only jump more or less high, but can't move right or left (like the dino game on Chrome when there's no Internet connexion).

After many unsuccessful attempts to detect if the player is above (it's not simply `if (PlayerY - MonsterY) > 0` otherwise I wouldn't ask here), the best idea I came up with is to make two colliders in the monster: one for the "`head`", and one for the "`body`".

- When the player hits only the head it can only be above (otherwise it's the body first), so it's an easy situation
- When the player hits only the body it can only be below or on the sides, so it's an easy situation too
- sometimes, it happens that the player hits *both* colliders.

So I'd like to check this *after* the `FixedUpdate` calculations.

If you read the [execution order of the callback functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), there's no `LateFixedUpdate`: even though there's a `LateUpdate`, it's officially written that the developer should handle physics in `FixedUpdate`, and **nowhere else**.

What I've done so far is: when the `OnCollision` of monster head is called, just change a boolean, and same for `OnCollision` of the monster body. So after the OnCollisionXXX, like the documentation says, there's only one thing you can use: `yield WaitForFixedUpdate`.

I'd like to check those booleans and act according to their values in the `yield WaitForFixedUpdate`.

I can't find any valuable example on the net on how to do this. Any idea how to implement `yield WaitForFixedUpdate` in this situation? I'm stuck.

Comment: what is a `a 2D + 3D world`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the question

> how to implement yield WaitForFixedUpdate

The `yield` is ment to be used inside of a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

`yield` kind of reads like "interupt the routine here, render the current frame and continue from here in the next frame."

e.g.

```c#
private void Start()
{
    // Start the routine once
    StartCoroutine(LateFixedUpdate());
}

private IEnumerator LateFixedUpdate()
{
    // looks scary but is okey in a Coroutine 
    // as long as you yield somewhere inside of the loop
    while(true)
    {
        // Continue after all FixedUpdate has been called on all scripts
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        // do something
    }
}
```